# What ios app makes possible to do this 'halo' effect?

Tags: lighting

I mean there is some lighting effect above a person.

[image]

Comment: Please see http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/psa-on-whats-this-effect-questions — could you describe the effect you are seeing more specifically, and, especially, edit that description into the title question? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like a typically HDR type of artifact. Most of the sophisticated image manip programs will do it. Its more a matter of technique.

Comment: It is unlikely that someone made an app to simulate a mistake or do something undesirable. WAIT,  now that i think about it, there are lots of apps that do just that. Apps that simulate mistakes in post processing and turn good or even ok photos into crappy photos. So you could create the app and make a fortune because there seems to be no end to the demand for such apps.   *Rants by Alaska Man are purely his own opinion and for entertainment proposes only.*

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're seeing the same thing I'm seeing: a lighter "halo" in the sky around the man on the left, and possibly also around some of the people near the river, I think it's not an intentional lighting effect but an accidental artifact.

My guess is that in the original exposure, the man was very, very underexposed. Post-processing techniques — possibly blending multiple exposures with HDR — were used to brighten it up. But this wasn't done carefully, and also caused brightening in the already-bright sky. This kind of halo is a very common artifact from this kind of brightness manipulation.

Comment: Hey, thanks fro answer. But do you know what program is used to create this 'halo' effect on ios? :)

Comment: Any program which will attempt to adjust exposure of shadow areas. Could be the built in HDR, even, although I haven't used that.